# Android- When I call the onClick_Start method, the app crashes

Tags: android, loops, while-loop, crash

```
 Button StopB = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stop_Button);
    StopB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            stop = true; 
        }
    });

}

//When the user clicks the start button
public void onClick_Start(View v)
{
    counter = 0;
    condition = true;

    while(condition)
    {
        if(mLastX == -1)
        {
            counter++;
        }
       if(stop)
           condition = false;

    }
}
```

- Trying to count a movement a certain x values.
- App keeps crashing every time I hit the start button
- Cannot seem to fix
- If anyone sees a problem please let me know!
- The button is declared inside of the onCreate method

Comment: The answer below is correct, you are blocking the UI thread with a loop that cannot exit hence your app is being killed as non-responsive. An Async task will allow your loop to run on a background thread whilst also updating your UI as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Code inside `onClick_Start` take control of UI thread. Nothing else in the UI thread, will be execute untill you exit from `onClick_Start`.

Use AsyncTask to execute background task.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

Execute onClick_Start method in AsyncTask. Long running operation like your while loop on UI Thread is not good. That's why you're experiencing ANR ERROR